# Why is the Return keyword not working in VB.NET? Why is the value of my variable = Nothing?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following functions.
When I call `getQueryObject(jsonString)` It makes the coll parses the object then returns.
The the assignment to `jsonObject` is not working. When I start operating on the `jsonObject` bariable it has the value *nothing*.
I run Debug and follow the code and the `jsonObject` in `getQueryObject` is not failing. and return says it returns the object.

I am new to VB is there something I am missing?

```
Public Function getInformation(jsonString as string) as string
    Dim jsonObject As JObject
    jsonObject = getQueryObject(jsonString)
    'Operate on object here.
End Function

Private Function getQueryObject(jsonString as string) As JObject
    Dim jsonObject As JObject
    Try
        jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        jsonObject = New JObject
    End Try
    Return jsonObject
End Function
```

A little more information. After I turned on **Option strict** I started to get an error. Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Newtonsoft.Jsont.Linq.Token to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

I don's see where I am making any type of conversion.

Comment: What is the JSON string value?

Comment: It is @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

Comment: and so if you follow the code through, after you call JObject.Parse, can you see those values in "jsonObject" before it is returned? Is it possible that it is returning correctly, but the call to Parse is returning nothing?

Comment: I made a typo in the simplification of my code. The variables have the same name in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've used in the incorrect variable name in the `getInformation` function.

Change your code to look like this, instead:

```
Public Function GetInformation(jsonString as string) as string
    Dim jsonObj As JObject
    jsonObj = GetQueryObject(jsonString)  // Change the name of this variable
                                          // to match the declaration above it.
    'Operate on object here.
End Function
```

Or even simpler, declare and initialize the variable in the same line:

```
Public Function GetInformation(jsonString as string) as string
    Dim jsonObj As JObject = GetQueryObject(jsonString)
    'Operate on object here.
End Function
```

If you were compiling your code with [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) and [`Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) both turned **on**, the compiler would have caught this problem for you. Change those settings in your project's Properties. ***NEVER*** write code in VB.NET with `Option Explicit` turned off. Unexpected things happen.

What's happening is that VB.NET is letting you use the `jsonObject` variable *without ever declaring it*. The compiler just automagically initializes it to `Nothing` behind the scenes, which is the default value. It's a simple enough mistake to make, since that's the name of the variable in the *other* method. But it doesn't work as expected, because it's not the name of the variable in *this* method. As long as you have`Option Explicit` off, VB.NET doesn't warn you, and blissfully compiles wrong code.

(Note that I'm also following the recommended .NET coding convention of CamelCasing all method names. That means they should start with a *capital* letter, rather than a lower-case letter. Only local variables and parameters should be pascalCased (initial lower-case).)

Comment: great catch, I did not notice that! :)

Comment: Thank you for help with finding Option Strict. This is very useful. But the problem does not seem to be solved by renaming the methods.

Comment: @Whitecat: Renaming the *variables*, you mean? Renaming the *methods* was just a stylistic thing, it won't affect how your code runs. If this isn't the answer, then I'm not sure what to tell you...the code you've shown runs just fine for me. The only other thing to consider is if `JObject.Parse` is throwing an exception inside of the `getQueryObject` method, and your code is catching that to return an empty `JObject` by calling the default constructor.

Comment: I have run my code with a debugger and it does not hit the catch statement. I do get a strange error when I turned on Option Strict *Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Newtonsoft.Jsont.Linq.Token to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.*

Comment: This was not the correct answer but it helped me to find what was wrong. I was referencing a Method that did not exist. I had removed the variables passed in the getQueryObject() method.  VB did not catch this mistake.  I was calling getQueryObject(jsonString) when it should have been getQueryObject().

Comment: @Whitecat: If the method prototype does not accept any parameters, then VB will definitely not let you pass any arguments in a call to that method. It results in a compiler error. I know because I've made the same mistake multiple times myself, only to be caught by the inevitable compiler error. Something is wrong with your project settings if it's *not* catching that error. Anyway, I'm glad you were able to solve the problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function getInformation(jsonString as string) as string
    Dim jsonObj As JObject
    jsonObject = getQueryObject(jsonString)
    'Operate on object here.
End Function
```

Is jsonObject declared globally?

Comment: No jsonObject is not declared globally.

Comment: I guess Cody said what I was getting at.  I didn't see where you Dim'd jsonObject locally or globaly.

Comment: Yeah, ordinarily this type of mistake should just give you a compiler error. In fact, with the default settings, it should give you a compiler error. But I'm assuming that `Option Explicit` must have *somehow* gotten inadvertently turned off, in which case VB.NET will happily let you write code that doesn't make any sense. :-) That's the first thing to check.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I was thinking.